# Not able to load the Kernel Modules in WLS

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kernel

I am trying to up a Vagrant box on my WLS.
I installed Virtual box and then and I tried to do vagrant up and it threw the following error.

`VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded. Please
run VBoxManage --version or open the VirtualBox GUI to see the error
message which should contain instructions on how to fix this error.`

And then I gave `VBoxManage --version`

It threw the following error

`libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1657 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.4.0-17134-Microsoft) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
   You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.2.28r130011`

Then I tried /sbin/vboxconfig from root as well.

`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1657 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to up a Vagrant box on my WLS.

The current version of `Windows Linux Subsystem` does not support what you want.  What you want to do won't be possible until WSL runs the full Linux kernel.

> WSL 2 uses the latest and greatest in virtualization technology to run its Linux kernel inside of a lightweight utility virtual machine (VM).
>
> Initial builds of WSL 2 will be available through the Windows Insider program by the end of June 2019.

Source: [Announcing WSL 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/)